# How do I find a Stronghold on a live map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've had the fun of finding the end legitimately many times, now on my current server I just want to go to it quickly without hassle. My server has a live map but I don't know what to look for to find the end portal quickly. How can I quickly find the stronghold using the live map?

Comment: Do you mean the stronghold? The End is in a different dimension, same as the Nether, so can't be seen from a map. Also, Strongholds are usually underground so it'd be hard to see one on a map. Your best bet is probably to /give yourself loads of eyes of ender and find it the traditional way.

Comment: Oh yes, i meant the stronghold entrance. I guess i'll load up on ender eyes and go do it later tonight. Thanks.

Comment: what's a live map? how is this question differnt from finding a stronghold in any other map?

Comment: The server's livemap will probably not help you at all, unless you are the server operator.

Comment: O I see, you want to find it using the Live Map Interface, rather than actually finding it in the Minecraft Game Interface...

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to find a stronghold is to set your live map to only show cracked/mossy stone brick blocks. These only occur naturally in strongholds.

Answer (score -1):

you make a 3x3 with end portal blocks and put eyes of ender in the same direction